# Back chain validation under node failures in R3 Corda

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda. My question is not about any particular implementation, but more of an architectural question.

What happens during back chain validation if one of the nodes involved permanently dies and fails to respond? How is that transaction validated?

I have seen [this issue](https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-3295?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true) that only talks about how of transaction volume could slow down validation. Does validation come to a grinding halt if one of the nodes fails permanently?

As per [Corda webinar on Consensus](https://player.vimeo.com/video/214138438), in the example that is 5 minutes into the video, the back chain is Charlie -> Dan -> Alice -> Bob. In this, if either Charlie or Dan are unavailable, the proposed transaction cannot be validated. The same webinar further says that this is not a problem in other blockchains such as Ethereum.

Applications that can foresee the need for a highly-available record keeper, can surely accommodate such a node during the design phase, as suggested by Adel Rustum.

However, a privacy-conscious application reluctant to leak information that is deployed globally, could suffer from many transaction-validation failures due to the vagaries of a wide-area network. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

1. The short answer is, transaction verification will fail (if that node was the only node that had that transaction); and that's the point of using a DLT (or a blockchain). If you can't go back in the history of a certain block of data until genesis, then you can't verify how that block and its ancestors were created.
2. As for the issue that you referenced in your question; Corda Enterprise 4.4 introduced a new feature called bulk back-chain fetching, which allows modifying the way the transactions that are needed to verify a certain transaction are fetched. Previously it was depth first, now you can change that to breadth first and specify how many transactions you want to fetch in one call. More details in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muQxj7iyaAs).

Comment: Is it fare to say then that in a long chain A->B->C->D ..., there are as many single-points failures as ancestors that could halt validation? According to the Corda privacy model, unlike in other DLTs, only two nodes would be aware of any single link in this scenario, and failure of either one could be problematic, right?

Comment: Correction to your statement: not "only two nodes"; it all depends on who are the participants in your state, it could be any number of parties (that's something you decide in your design phase).

Comment: All participants register the transaction in their transaction storage and the resulting states in their vault. So the chain is not always linear, it's more like a tree; if a transaction had 3 participants then A can have 3 branches under it (A->B1, A->B2, A->B3) so it can request that transaction from any of those 3 participants. Also Corda Enterprise offers high availability nodes where each node is copied and you can do a hot/cold swap, plus you need to backup your node's database regularly; so a failure scenario is highly unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

The back chain validation doesn't depend on the nodes who were part of the transaction in the past. The validation of the back chain is only done by those nodes who are part of the current ongoing transaction. The other nodes who were part of a past transaction that involves the evolution of a state in question don't need to be contacted (or stay online) while the back chain is validated.

Back chain validation only involves checking that all transaction which happened in the past on a particular state used as input in the current transaction is valid. The validity is checked by running the contracts again for those previous transactions. There is no real need to reach to the parties of a previous transaction.

However, you need to make sure that the parties involved in the current transaction are online and responding since you would need signatures from them to successfully complete the transaction.

Comment: Ashutosh, when a transaction is validated and it has inputs; the transactions that generated those inputs (as outputs at the time) will also need to be validated in a recursive way until we get a fully validated graph (thus the term back chain validation), and if the current node doesn’t have those transactions, it will request them from the nodes that were participants in those transactions. So, RT’s question is: What happens if one of the nodes that has one of the transactions (that is required for back chain validation) is down, or deleted. I don’t think your answer is correct.

Comment: Ahh! I misunderstood the question. Thanks for correcting me there. :)

Comment: @AdelRustum - Wouldnt the node (B) sharing the transaction with the new node (C) having the entire backchain already? (as part when it resolved this transaction). Why would C have to contact a node involved earlier in the transaction (A). B would have the full chain, which it can share with C. Why would there be a dependency on A?

Comment: @AmolPednekar good question, honestly I don't know the full details of the resolution of a transaction; maybe when it resolves a transaction it requests the previous transactions but doesn't store them; that's why it has to contact node A in your example. Again, you'd have to research that. Let me know if you find the answer :-)